# Perl - count number of columns per row in a csv file

Tags: perl, csv

I want to count the number of columns in a row for a CSV file.

row 1 10 columns
row 2 11 columns
etc.

I can print out the value of the last column, but I really just want a count per row.

```
perl -F, -lane "{print @keys[$_].$F[$_] foreach(-1)}" < testing.csv
```

I am on a windows machine

Thanks.

Comment: Does your CSV file contain quoted delimiters? E.g. `1,"foo,bar",2` (note the embedded comma).

Comment: This particular file does not have embedded commas, so the solution by Olaf directly below works well.  I will also test out the other condition noted below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a proper csv file, it can contain embedded delimiters (e.g. `1,"foo,bar",2`), in which case a simple split will not be enough. You can use the Text::CSV module fairly easily with a one-liner like this:

Copy/paste version:

```
perl -MText::CSV -lwe"my $c=Text::CSV->new({sep_char=>','}); while($r=$c->getline(*STDIN)) { print scalar @$r }" < sorted.csv
```

Readable version:

```
perl -MText::CSV            # use Text::CSV module
     -lwe                   # add newline to print, use warnings
         "my $c = Text::CSV->new();             # set up csv object 
          while( $r = $c->getline(*STDIN) ) {   # get lines from stdin
              print scalar @$r                  # print row size
          }" < sorted.csv                       # input file to stdin
```

If your input can be erratic, Text::CSV->getline might choke on corrupted lines (the `while` loop is ended), in which case it may be safer to use plain parsing:

```
perl -MText::CSV -nlwe"
    BEGIN { $r = Text::CSV->new() }; 
    $r->parse($_); 
    print scalar $r->fields
" comma.csv
```

Note that in this case we use a different input method. This is because while `getline()` requires a file handle, `parse()` does not. Since the diamond operator uses either ARGV or STDIN depending on your argument, I find it is better to be explicit.

Comment: Good point. My current file doesn't have the embedded commas within a field/column, but I know I will encounter it.  I will test out this solution as well. Thank You.

Comment: @John If you find this answers your question, mark the answer as accepted by clicking the check mark.

Comment: I found a large file with double quoted commas. I had to install the Text::CSV module first (cpan -i Text::CSV). The data was erratic, so the first example failed on me. I modified the second example slightly to include binary, { $r = Text::CSV->new( { binary => 1 } )  }, because I had a lot of unitialized errors. I still have a few errors, but I can see in notepad++ that they are LF in the middle of a field. I will figure that out eventually since I believe I am on the right track.

Comment: Had to just remove those lines(they ended up showing blank number of columns because they errored out, so it was easy to find them.)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have commas as part of the fields, you can `split` the line and count the number of fields

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @cols = split(',', $_);
my $n = @cols;
print "row $. $n columns\n";
```

you can call this

```
perl -n script.pl testing.csv
```

Comment: This would work a lot more reliably if it wasn't possible to have commas inside field values in a CSV file, e.g. `field 1,"field 2, which is my favourite","field 3",field 4\n"`